# kubernetes can't resolve dns name for the service in aws

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-route53

I created a service in k8s cluster which is on aws cloud

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service 
metadata:
  name: widget-svc
  labels: 
    app: widget-test
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - port: 3000
    nodePort: 30003
    protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: widget-test
```

My deployment.yml:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata: 
  name: widget-deploy
spec:
  replicas: 10
  template:
   metadata:
     labels:
     app: widget-test
   spec:
    containers:
    - name: widget-pod
      image: xxxxx/xxx:xxx
      ports:
      - containerPort: 3000
```

I can access the service through loadbalancer endpoint on port 3000 but when i create a dns name for the loadbalancer in route 53, I can't access service through DNS name.

Comment: Without the information of how R53 has been configured, would be difficult to help.

Comment: my cluster dns zone is yupl.us and i configure my load balancer DNS as widgetdock.yupl.us, my domain is in godaddy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The configured CNAME `a301877583cad11e8b74b0ab1dd411bf-51616161.us-east-2.elb.amazonaws.com` does not exist:

```
$ dig widgetdock.yupl.us

; <<>> DiG 9.10.6 <<>> widgetdock.yupl.us
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 42278
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;widgetdock.yupl.us.        IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
widgetdock.yupl.us. 300 IN  CNAME   a301877583cad11e8b74b0ab1dd411bf-51616161.us-east-2.elb.amazonaws.com.

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
us-east-2.elb.amazonaws.com. 60 IN  SOA ns-1076.awsdns-06.org. awsdns-hostmaster.amazon.com. 1 7200 900 1209600 60

;; Query time: 73 msec
;; SERVER: 172.31.254.1#53(172.31.254.1)
;; WHEN: Thu Apr 26 15:22:30 CEST 2018
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 212
```

See the `status: NXDOMAIN` which means this domain does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this, the issue is with the security group rules for the load balancer. after allowing security group rules, it's working fine